# Create a mapping which depends on an "argument keystroke"

Tags: key-bindings

Say I want to copy what `f` does. f takes an "argument" keystroke and moves the cursor there. How do I create such a mapping?

I want to have a functionality that would require me to have a character as an argument. I'm not looking for the exact, or even close, functionality of `f`

Comment: Use `y/` + the desired keystroke? :) (so create a map for `y/`) - it has the advantage that it works on multiple lines, can search for more than one char, but you have to hit Enter.

Comment: @VanLaser Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm not looking for that exact functionality.

Comment: Ok, you probably want to use `:h getchar()` in a function.

Comment: Also, `yf` + `<a char>` "to copy what f does" (so - map `yf`)

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?  `f` doesn't take arguments, it's a _motion_ (see `:h left-right-motions`) that can be used with _operators_ (see `:h operator`; in fact read the entire `:h motion.txt`, about everything there is very useful).  So, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `getchar()`. Since that usually returns a number, convert the result back to a String:

```
let char = nr2char(getchar())
```

This is not a full equivalent of what the built-in `f` does; for example, it doesn't handle *digraphs* (i.e. `<C-K>xy` combinations).

If you use this in a mapping, ensure that all keys from the mapping have been consumed, or wrap the `getchar()` around `inputsave()` / `inputrestore()`.